# Specifying the offset and limit in a Redmine REST API request with Ruby

Tags: ruby, api, redmine

I'm using the Ruby REST API for Redmine (here: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api_with_ruby). I need to be able to get all issues in a chunk of 100 at a time.

I know there is an options[:offset] and an options[:limit] that the method "api_offset_and_limit" is looking for.

How do I pass those options when I'm doing this? I tried putting them in the URL as GET options, but they didn't come through on the other end. The following gives me the first 25 issues, as I expect it to.

```
class Issue < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = 'http://redmine.server/'
  self.user = 'foo'
  self.password = 'bar'
end

# Retrieving issues
issues = Issue.find(:all)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the API, but the way you describe it, the following should work:

```
issues = Issue.find(:all, :params => {:offset => 0, :limit => 100})
```